# Learn UI arts design for Android and iOS app

Tags: android, ios, user-interface

I plan to develop my own Android and iOS app. I know how to write the code, but didn't learn UI design before. Can anyone recommend to me any tutorials or books on UI arts design for background, icon, layout, colors, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: Start with [Android Developers Guide](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html)

Comment: why down-voted this question? Is there anything wrong with this question?

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but Stack Overflow is dedicated to programming questions. The question is a little broad, too. "Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the scope defined in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)." Nonetheless, I hope some of the answers below helped. Admittedly, I think we're a little too quick to dismiss legitimate development questions because their not related to the actual code, but that is the charter of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently bought [Mobile Design Pattern Gallery](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022367.do) . It has alot of UI Patterns for mobile Apps.

You can also look at [User Interface Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html) for android

and  [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) for IOS

Answer (score 0):

The WWDC 2012 [iOS User Interface Design](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=221) video describes a few pitfalls that iOS developers should be wary of. As Frank said, the [iOS HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a good resource for tactical design considerations, too.